# get integers from string

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, parsing

i have in the database data like this

```
61/10#61/12,0/12,10/16,0/21,0/12#61/33,0/28#0/34,0/23#0/28
```

where the part like `10/16`(without `#`) is invalid should not use for the calculation,

but all other has next format `min_hr + "/" + min_hrv + "#" + max_hr + "/" + max_hrv`

and the issue is get AVG value by next psevdo formula `[ summ(all(min_hrv)) + summ(all(max_hrv)) ] / count(all(min_hrv)) + all(max_hrv))`, for the axample string result will be `((10 + 12 + 28 + 23) + (12 + 33 + 34 + 28))/8)` == `22`

What i try is:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
    '61/10#61/12,0/12,10/16,0/21,0/12#61/33,0/28#0/34,0/23#0/28',
    ',\d+/\d+,', ',',
    'g'
);
```

to remove invalid data but `10/16` still in the strin, result is:

```
                  regexp_replace                  
--------------------------------------------------
 61/10#61/12,10/16,0/12#61/33,0/28#0/34,0/23#0/28
```

if do good clean the string my plan is split to array some way like this, for max (not full solution, has empty string), has no solution for min:

```
SELECT 
    regexp_split_to_array(
        regexp_replace(
            '61/10#61/12,0/12,0/12#61/33,0/28#0/34,0/23#0/28',
            ',\d+/\d+,', ',',
            'g'
        )
        ,',?\d+/\d+#\d+/'
    );
```

result is:

```
 regexp_split_to_array 
-----------------------
 {"",12,33,34,28}
```

and then calculate the data, something like this:

```
SELECT ((
    SELECT sum(tmin.unnest)
    FROM
        (SELECT unnest('{10,12,28,23}'::int[])) as tmin
    ) 
    + 
    (
    SELECT sum(tmax.unnest)
    FROM
        (SELECT unnest('{12,33,34,28}'::int[])) as tmax
    ))
    /
    (SELECT array_length('{12,33,34,28}'::int[], 1) * 2)
```

may be some one know more simple and right way for such issue?

Comment: Try `',\d+/\d+(?=,)'` with `regexp_replace`

Comment: Or, it seems you may just use `unnest(regexp_matches('61/10#61/12,0/12,10/16,0/21,0/12#61/33,0/28#0/34,0/23#0/28', '#\d+/(\d+)', 'g'))` if you need to get `12`, `33`, `34` and `28`. The regex to match all the items is most likely `'(\d+)/(\d+)#(\d+)/(\d+)'`, you just need to keep one set of brackets to extract these specific data with `regexp_matches`.

Comment: the second solution is brings us near the victory, thank you.

Comment: Please see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54762531/3832970) below, and let know what is still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_matches()`:

```
select (regexp_matches(
    '61/10#61/12,0/12,0/12#61/33,0/28#0/34,0/23#0/28', 
    '\d+#\d+/(\d+)', 
    'g'))[1]

 regexp_matches 
----------------
 12
 33
 34
 28
(4 rows)
```

The whole calculation may look like this:

```
with my_data(str) as (
values
    ('61/10#61/12,0/12,10/16,0/21,0/12#61/33,0/28#0/34,0/23#0/28')
),
min_max as (
    select 
        (regexp_matches(str, '(\d+)#\d+', 'g'))[1] as min_hrv,
        (regexp_matches(str, '\d+#\d+/(\d+)', 'g'))[1] as max_hrv
    from my_data
)

select avg(min_hrv::int+ max_hrv::int) / 2 as result
from min_max;

       result        
---------------------
 22.5000000000000000
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are looking for should match the digits after `#`, a streak of digits and a `/` char. With [`regexp_matches`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#regexp_matches), you may extract a *part* of the pattern only if you wrap that part within a pair of parentheses.

The solution is

```
regexp_matches(your_col, '#\d+/(\d+)', 'g')
```

Note that `g` stands for `global`, meaning that all occurrences found in the string will be returned.

**Pattern details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more (`+`) digits
- `/` - a `/`char
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1:  1 or more digits

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VKBwKL/1).

You may extract specific bits from your data if you use a single pair of parentheses in different parts of the `'(\d+)/(\d+)#(\d+)/(\d+)'` regex. To extract `min_hr`, you'd use `'(\d+)/\d+#\d+/\d+'`.

Comment: thank you, need time to understand and write full solution, in progress

Comment: @BearBrown If you need any further help, please let know.

Comment: you give me the many details how the `regexp_matches` it is very helpful for me, but the second answer(after edited) give me the full soolution.